# Programatically move to specific tab in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have my custom app developed and deployed to MS Teams. I would like to navigate from one Tab to another tab programmatically.

For Example, There is one link in the Home Tab, Once clicked it should activate the Overview tab programmatically.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "deeplink to tab" to navigate to specific tab.

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/<appId>/<entityId>?webUrl=<entityWebUrl>&label=<entityLabel>&context=<context>
```

To navigate from one Tab to another tab

```
microsoftTeams.executeDeepLink("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/entity/fe4a8eba-2a31-4737-8e33-e5fae6fee194/tasklist123?webUrl=https://tasklist.example.com/123&label=Task List 123&context={"channelId": "19:cbe3683f25094106b826c9cada3afbe0@thread.skype"}");
```

For more info please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab).

Comment: @SigarDave please let us know if your issue has been resolved?

Comment: Yes, I have used deeplink for this